# Wifi and sound on a Lenovo Ideapad 100s with Lubuntu

Tags: wireless, sound, lubuntu, lenovo, ideapad

So I managed to install Lubuntu on my 100s, despite hearing of the difficulties (AFTER I had bought the thing). Despite being completely new to Linux, I was persistent and did it. For those who would like to know here's how: I downloaded the 64bit ISO as well as ELILO and bootia32.efi files, putting them both in the EFI/boot folder, without deleting the 64bit boot or grub files. Then I ran Lubuntu and GParted the disc, completely formatting it, and made a EXT4 partiton and a Linux swap partition. Then I tried the install, allowing the installer to 'force install' an efi/bios when prompted.

Anyway, now to my question. Having done that, I'm stuck using a USB wifi dongle and there's no sound. Would anyone be able to suggest steps to remedy that? When I go to additional drivers, no wifi shows up, nor does any wifi card or sound card show up when I run lspci in the terminal.

As I say - total newbie, though from what I've read here and elsewhere there've been many people trying unsuccessfully to get Linux on their 100s. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed UbuntuStudio on my 100S and the wifi just works.  Maybe the different/later kernel now has it working.

Still no sound from the internal hardware though. Works fine with external soundcard/DAC, which is OK for Studio I suppose.